# Parse poorly formatted strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

So, my issue is I have a very messy database (a Plex ERP database that I can not alter) and it has the dimensions store in a description in the format number space x space number.  I need to get those numbers, and use them for an operation. I was able to make a regex, but it seems like SQL may not support normal regexes, and I tried to make a sql pattern, but that left all the bits afterwards and I could figure out how to cut out the end.  Is there a good way to go about this?   Note, both of those numbers may have decimal places.  Thank you.

Edit:  In case it's not clear, the issue is there is text placed around the section I want to pull the numbers out of, and does not follow any pattern nor have standard lengths or numbers of words.

Here's a sample of data I want to parse

```
SPH 270 2.3 x 340 CPS
SCGA270D-45 1.4 x 486
```

I want to get 2.3 and 340 out of the first as numbers, and the 1.4 and 486 out of the second.

This is my latest attempt to get the formatted chunk out,  but I still have the CPS at the end, like in the first example.

```sql
SUBSTRING(cpart.Name, PATINDEX('%[0-9.] x [0‐9], cpart.Name), LEN(cpart.Name))
```

Comment: Sample data, expected results and your attempt(s) will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu does this seem about right, or is there more information that would be helpful for me to post?

Comment: So this does show what you're asking now. As, however, you have discovered, SQL Server does *not* support Regex. If you *must* use Regex you'll need to implement CLR Functions. What you could, however, likely do is use a string splitter than provides the ordinal position, and then return the rows where the next or prior row had the value `'x'`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the extracted numbers?  You might be better to create a query to just bring the strings out and parse them in a different language.

Comment: @Sparky I can't actually use anything outside of SQL for the logic in the software.   I'm also limited on what SQL functions and commands I can use.  I can not alter or drop any tables, for instance.   I want to use two of the dimensions, and the weight, as well as the density (which is assumed the same between steels) to calculate the third dimension.   I'd rather not do this, but this is what I've been tasked with, since there is no third dimension in any of the records.

Comment: Can you create a UDF?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain that's not locked off.

Comment: I have a function in SQL that will do it for you.  If the question gets re-open, I'll send you the function.   SQL isn't good at string maniupulation,but this function will do the trick.                                                                                                                                 
select dbo.extractSizes'SPH 270 2.3 x 340 CPS')  = 2.3 X 340
select dbo.extractSizes('SCGA270D-45 1.4 x 486') = 1.4 X 486

Comment: "SQL" does support regex, but SQL Server (and it's T-SQL dialect) doesn't. SQL <> SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns).

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @strings TABLE (string VARCHAR(30))
INSERT @strings VALUES('SPH 270 2.3 x 340 CPS'),('SCGA270D-45 1.4 x 486')

SELECT f.String, f.Item
FROM
(
  SELECT s.String, ps.Item,
    Back1  = LAG(ps.Item,1)  OVER (PARTITION BY s.String ORDER BY ps.ItemNumber),
    Ahead1 = LEAD(ps.Item,1) OVER (PARTITION BY s.String ORDER BY ps.ItemNumber)
  FROM        @strings AS s
  CROSS APPLY PerfLib.dbo.PatternSplitCM(s.string,'[0-9.]') AS ps 
) AS f
WHERE ' x ' IN (Back1, Ahead1);
```

**Returns:**

```
String                  Item
----------------------- -------
SCGA270D-45 1.4 x 486   1.4
SCGA270D-45 1.4 x 486   486
SPH 270 2.3 x 340 CPS   2.3
SPH 270 2.3 x 340 CPS   340
```

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns

Comment: Very creative solution, thanks for sharing it.   I agree UDF's are a slow solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL UDF that will do what you are looking for.    That being said, string manipulation is not SQL's strong point, so if you have better options available, I would consider those first.

```
create function dbo.extractSizes(@ex varchar(50))
returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    declare @x int = charindex(' x ',@ex)
    declare @nextspace int = charindex(' ',@ex,@x+2)
    declare @2nd varchar(10) = substring(@ex,@x+3,(@nextSpace-@x)+1)
    declare @rest varchar(50) = rtrim(substring(@ex,1,@x))
    declare @next int = charindex(' ',reverse(@rest))
    declare @1st varchar(10) = reverse(substring(reverse(@rest),1,@next))
    return ltrim(@1st+' X '+@2nd)
end
go

declare @ex1 varchar(50)='SPH 270 2.3 x 340 CPS'
declare @ex2 varchar(50)='SCGA270D-45 1.4 x 486'

select dbo.extractSizes(@ex1)
select dbo.extractSizes(@ex2)
```

This is something I put together quickly with minimal testing, but it should give you a starting point

Comment: T-SQL scalar UDFs are horribly slow and inefficient - armed with some good set-based thinking and a good N-Grams function, SQL server can parse strings as well as any other programming language or tool. It's about the algorithm, not the programming language.